# Can´t find dll file when I run the executable Java file out off NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, dll

I have the problem that my Java program runs fine, when I start it throw the NetBeans IDE (V.: 8.0.2) but when I start the application form the windows file browser, it won´t find the dll file.

I have to support the eaapi (API form the Enterprise Architect) and this API need the SSJavaCOM.dll.
I placed it in C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath and it works from the NetBeans IDE (is the file not available in this directory, it doesn´t work).

I don´t understand why the program runs fine, when I use the "Run Project" function and fails when I run it throw a double click on the jar file.

My compile options: `-Xlint:unchecked`

I´m using Windows 7 x64 with JRE 1.8.065 (x64) and 1.8.060 (x86).

Comment: `SSJavaCOM.dll` must be found in a directory which is in the execution `PATH` or is specified with the JVM option `-Djava.library.path` or in the current directory (from where you start you *.jar file).

Comment: See the additional hint from http://shapechange.net/app-schemas/ea/: To process Enterprise Architect models with ShapeChange, copy the file SSJavaCom.dll located in <EA installation folder>/Java API to <Windows folder>/System32 (on a 32-bit machine) or to <Windows folder>/SysWOW64 (on a 64-bit machine). On the 64-bit machine use the java.exe in the <Windows folder>/SysWOW64 folder since Enterprise Architect is a 32-bit application.

Comment: Thanks @mliebelt. That was the problem.